# Sketch a graph of a function that satisfies all of the following conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

- Even and continuous
- Zeroes at $\pm2,4$
- $y$-intercept $=-3$
- Increasing for $x\in(-\infty,-3)\cup(0,3)$
- Decreasing for $x\in(-3,0)\cup(3,\infty)$

Can someone walk me through how to do these types of questions so I will be able to do similar problems?

Thank you

Comment: Where would you start? Which parts can you do?

Comment: First plot the given points, +- 2 and 4 and the Y-int -3, I don't understand the increasing at x∈(−∞,−3) part

Comment: OK do that. Then connect the dots using the information about where the function is increasing. It's probably easiest to do that for positive $x$, which will finish the problem since the function is even. There's at least one more zero not mentioned in the problem because ...

Answer (score 0):

For a graph like this, I'd start with the given points. You can plot the $y$-intercept at $(0,-3)$, and $x$-intercepts at $(2,0),(-2,0),(4,0),(-4,0)$.

Now, since it's an even function, we can just plot the right side, i.e., the part of the graph where $x$ is positive, and then a mirror image will give you the left side.

Starting from the $y$-intercept, it looks like your function increases from $x=0$ until $x=3$. That includes passing through the $x$-intercept at $(2,0)$. Thus, there must be some local maximum at $(3,y)$, where $y$ is some positive value. After that, the function decreases again, passing through the other positive $x$-intercept at $(4,0)$, and then continuing to decrease forever.

Beyond that, it seems that you have a lot of freedom. The graph could consist of straight line segments, or of curves. It just has to satisfy the vertical line test, and it has to be symmetric, because it's even.

Does this give you a push in the right direction?